# How can I exclude packages with Plant UML yaml

Tags: plantuml

I'm attempting to make a component diagram with PlantUML. The problem I have is that I want my "common" component to include the set of packages, that include 'common'

```
package "Common Layer" {
  [Common] <<..common..>>
  [Something] <<com.xxx.yyy.common.somepkgs>>
}
```

imagine I have a class com.xxx.yyy.common.somepkgs.Something

but, because 'Something' is also 'common', this is leading to problems elsewhere. Ideally, I would like to describe my common layer as including all packages containing 'common', except com.xxx.yyy.common.somepkgs, which will be treated separately, as a different component called Something, The problem seems to be that when the diagram is being rendered; it thinks that Something belongs to two different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize how to exclude certain sub-packages, inside puml. Instead I reorganized my packages structure.

```
package "Common Layer" {
 [SomethingCommon] <<..common.something..>>
 [Something] <<com.xxx.yyy.common.somepkgs>>
}
```

I then replaced all references with both, instead of only one component reference. As follows:

```
[somethingElse] --> [Common]
```

became:

```
[somethingElse] --> [SomethingCommon]
[somethingElse] --> [Something]
```